# Updating some app text at user side - how to?

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio and I am creating an android application that contains a button in its main activity. The button takes the user to a new activity (intent) which contains a text in it and everyday the button should show a new text. As a developer, how can I update the text in the user app everyday so he can check the new text when he press this button?

Comment: What's your new text content?Please describe more details.

Comment: you can use api to update button text on daily basis and update text data in database on daily basis

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have stored all these texts that you want to be shown in the Button in `strings.xml` resources as a string array:

```
<string-array name="button_text">
    <item>text1</item>
    <item>text2</item>
    <item>text3</item>
    .................... 
    <item>text31</item>
</string-array>
```

In `onCreate()` of the activity class that contains the Button, write this code:

```
String[] texts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.button_text);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText(texts[today - 1]);
```

The above code will display a different text for each day of the month. 
This means that every 1st of every month it will start all over again.  
It's just an idea.  
You can have more texts in the string-array and by another way display a different text every day on the Button. 
Replace `button` with your Button's id.